# How to use SOAP Services in PCL for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm currently working on Xamarin.Android and xamarin.iOS project using mvvmcross.Now i have to consume Soap service  via PCL? How can I do that ?I have read in few tutorials that you have to generate the Proxy  class manually. Please let me know the feasible approach for this question.Also if there is any other way around.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not target Windows Phone 8.1 (which doesn't support SOAP out-of-the-box), you can just right click References in your PCL project and Add a new service reference. It will generate the proxies automatically as it would in a classic .NET project.

Comment: Naah! Xamarin does support only basic version of Soap service if you service is more customized and uses multiple layers of transport security xamarin is unable to create proxies then. Basically this is not limitation of Xamarin this is a mono limitation.